# SQL subqueries coding style

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to make this subqueries  to good-looking code? And I looking guides about SQL optimization and code style.

```
 SELECT foo FROM table WHERE foo_id IN 
    (
    SELECT idchild FROM table2 WHERE idparent IN 
    (SELECT idchild FROM table2 WHERE idparent IN 
    (SELECT idchild FROM table2 WHERE idparent = @id)
    ))
 AND txt_type ='some_cat'
```

Comment: The three-level nesting inside the query make me think that you are developing some sort of hierarchical query. In this case, [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)s may be of some help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance and readability, do this:

```
select t4.foo
from table2 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.idparent = t1.idchild
join table2 t3 on t3.idparent = t2.idchild
join table t4 on t4.foo_id = t3.idchild and t4.txt_type ='some_cat'
where t1.idparent = @id
```

Notice how the first table selected from has an indexed predicate in the where clause. This query will use indexed access all the way through the query and be very efficient.

Also notice how I moved the predicate for txt_type into the `on` clause, where it can be applied at the time the row is read, rather than after the joins have been assembled.

Comment: Edited: I altered the query slightly to improve performance - see last paragraph of answer

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
   Select a.foo,b.idchild from Table as a inner join table2 as b
   on a.foo_id=b.idchild and b.idparent=@id  AND a.txt_type ='some_cat'
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use **Praveen's** solution or following one. Both are properly optimized.

```
SELECT foo 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   table2 
               WHERE  idparent = @id 
                      AND table2.idchild = table1.foo_id) 
       AND txt_type = 'some_cat'
```